# Click to expand is working on jsfiddle but it's not working on wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Here is my code which i tried, and it's working fine on jsfiddle;

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattii/z5de0Ljs/61/)

```
function toggle(id) {
      a = document.getElementById('toggle_'+id);
      b = document.getElementById('display_'+id);
        if (a.style.display=='block') {
          a.style.display='none';
          b.innerHTML='Click to Expand';
        }
        else {
          a.style.display='block';
          b.innerHTML='Click to Hide';
      }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <h2><strong>HEADING</strong></h2>
    <a id="display_123" href="javascript:toggle('123');" style="color:black;font-weight:bold">Click To Expand</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Line 1</li>
    <span id="toggle_123" style="display: none">
        <li>Line 2</li>
        <li>Line 3</li>
    </span>
    </ul>
```

When I add the same code into my Wordpress website, it's toggling text click/hide, but it's not working to show/hide  elements even though it's working in fiddle.

[Website Link](https://ecommercefastlane.com/podcast/episode-80/)

i am using Insert header Footer to add jquery, and editing post in text mode to add  tag.

Comment: The HTML on your website does not match the HTML in the question. The difference is what breaks it. (It's likely caused by browsers being able to cope with the invalid HTML you've written, but WordPress' HTML editor doing error recovery in a different way that broke it horribly). Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

Comment: i used same list on fiddle aren't these same tags.

Comment: You didn't. Look at the HTML the browser receives from the website. It isn't the same.

Comment: how can i fix it, where to use validator?

Comment: Edit it so it matches the code in the question. You can use a validator by clicking the link in my earlier comment and using the simple UI there.

Comment: it matches the code in the question, still same

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UtbQtGB.png — It **does not** match.

Comment: i see this: https://imgur.com/a/KtpUMNR

Comment: That's your editor, not what is being set to the browser. I told you to look at what was being sent to the browser because it was likely that WordPress was breaking it.

Comment: i don't know how to use validator which you sent, any easy way to fix it?

Comment: Type the address of the page in the box marked "Address" then click Validate.

Comment: I've no idea how to fix it. I don't use Wordpress **because** it pulls this sort of horror.

Comment: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored. what's next

Comment: Fix the errors it has found, including the fatal one, then run it again.

Comment: can you share any other method to achieve same result?

Comment: hy, it worked i just added div instead of span.

Comment: The problem is because WP automatically adds `<p>` tags around linebreaks. This is a very common problem in WP and I've posted an answer below to show you how to get around that - even if you've found a way around it for now, you will probably run into it again in future so it should be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding HTML into the WP editor is not ideal, there are so many other more reliable ways to do that, from shortcodes to creating custom fields.

If you really need to do it the way you have shown in your question, there are a few ways to do it. The problem is because WP automatically adds `<p>` tags to all linebreaks.

**1. Don't use a span - Add the `toggle_id` reference to the list items directly as classes**

The working snippet below shows you that in action and doesn't have a new line in between that will be generated as a paragraph:

```js
function toggle(id) {

  var trigger = document.getElementById('display_' + id);
  var listitems = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle_'+id);
  for (i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
    if (listitems[i].style.display == 'block') {
      listitems[i].style.display = 'none';
      trigger.innerHTML = 'Click to Expand';
    } else {
      listitems[i].style.display = 'block';
      trigger.innerHTML = 'Click to Hide';
    }
  }
 }
```

```html
<h2><strong>HEADING</strong></h2>
<a id="display_123" href="#" onclick="toggle('123');" style="color:black;font-weight:bold">Click To Expand</a>
<ul>
  <li>Line 1</li>
  <li class="toggle_123" style="display: none">Line 2</li>
  <li class="toggle_123" style="display: none">Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

**2. Remove the `<p>` tags that WP automatically adds**

You can add the function below to your `functions.php` to disable WP from adding `<p>` tags for linebreaks... but note that this will affect ALL your content so you might want to make sure everything else will still work afte, or consider targeting specific pages:

```
// Prevent WP from adding <p> tags on all post types
function disable_wp_auto_p( $content ) {
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
  remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'disable_wp_auto_p', 0 );
```

**3. Shortcodes**

Its beyond the scope of this question, but for future projects you can consider using shortcodes to replace html in your content.

Shortcodes are code shortcuts that can be used to add dynamic content in the WordPress editor. Here's a great resource on What they are, how to use them and how to create your own [How to Add a Shortcode in WordPress? (Beginner's Guide)](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-shortcode-in-wordpress/)

Comment: i added div tag to replace spain, and it worked, is it ok? can you please tell me where to deal with html if not text editor, i am new to WordPress. Thanks

Comment: The main problems adding html into the editor are (2) How WP renders it, which is the problem you've run into here. Removing p tags (part 2 in my answer) will help with that. (2) it is every easy to break the html e.g. delete an ending tag by accident. If you're the only person updating the page its not so bad, but if others are updating the same page it can get very tricky. In that case try to minimise the need for HTML, like in part 1 of my answer - just look for a way to do the same thing without adding extra HTML elements.

Comment: how can i add new id in any element without editing html? through JavaScript? or any html editor?

Comment: For simple tasks, the easiest way to avoid adding HTML is to use shortcodes - I've updfated my answer to add a link to a very helpful resource about what they are, how to use them and how to create your own, so you can take a look at this for your future projects. If you give them a go and run into problems, you can come back and ask another question so we can help :)

Comment: "*how can i add new id in any element without editing html?*" You have to edit the html for that. But that's not a big deal as doesn't change how WP renders the content, so the only risk is if it's added/changed to be invalid (e.g. missing a quote). In that case, WP will remove the invalid attribute entirely, which could break your added functionality, but your page will still load and work properly. Another option is to look at adding custom fields where you add each element in its own field which makes it identifiable in the code, but that's quite advanced for what you are doing here.

Comment: Thanks man, shortcodes are amazing, you opened new world for me.

Comment: i am so sorry, Thankyou women for helping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

On your wordpress site the list elements are not surrounded by span element with the id `toggle_123`. If you add that it should work all good.

A slightly cleaner way to do this would be to have a css class with the `display: none;` property. You could then toggle this class with `classList.toggle`. It would save an if statement.

Exmaple:

```
    function toggle(id){
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.hide { 
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: but there is id toggle_123 for span